# Does the phrase "orbis terrarum" reflect Ancient Roman knowledge that the Earth is a sphere?

Tags: etymology, history, science

Does the phrase **orbis terrarum** reflect Ancient Roman knowledge that the Earth is a sphere?

Some kinds of evidence that might suggest an answer: Did people say **orbis terrarum** for the world before they knew that the Earth is spherical? Does **orbis** in this sense (meaning the world, without **terrarum**) suggest a sphere, or does it only suggest a circle?

Comment: The knowledge that it was spherical predates Classical Latin, though I'm not sure how widespread it was. I wonder when the oldest attestations of *orbis terrārum* are…

Comment: Even if not, _orbis_ could refer to the celestial sphere, since _terrarum_ is genitive

Comment: @Draconis. Orbis terrarum (or terrae) was used by Cicero.

Comment: @fdb True, but isn't Cicero just about the epitome of Classical? Eratosthenes calculated the circumference of the earth around 240 BC, so the idea of a spherical earth must have been fairly widespread by that point. And Plato said it was a sphere significantly earlier.

Comment: @Draconis. Everyone knew that the earth is a sphere. I did not wish to imply anything other.